# How to use local image for background image with fill option

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg 
xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' 
fill='%23ffffff'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 
1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 
0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;
```

Currently this uses external icon. I need to use a specific image from my local - /images/icon/svg which changes colors on multiple features. so want to change through fill option.

How can I update the URL to get both fill and image URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things :

1. Download that SVG (in SVG  format only ) and define its path on the background and manipulate its color through CSS.
2. you can change the try to change the "fill" prop in the URL it self.

Comment: where do we give path for local image for above url.

Comment: you can use the same way you used above, just make a separate folder,for example assests/image/back.svg

then use {
background-image: url("assests/image/back.svg") !important;
}